# How to login Firebase with Facebook on iOS for multiple added apps Firebase project

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

My Firebase project has 2 iOS apps and I've enabled Firebase login in Authentication Sign-In method.

I've also added my 2 iOS apps to Facebook and each app has its Facebook App ID and Secret key.

Firebase Facebook Sign In requires App ID and App Secret but I am not sure how I can add 2 apps App IDs and secret keys for 1 Firebase project so both apps can login with Facebook for this Firebase project.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me for this.

Comment: Found the solution?

Comment: yes, I've added 2 apps in 1 facebook app. Means I've used single fb app id for firebase authentication for 2 iOS apps. FB provide `UrlSchemePrefix` feature. You can reference more details about that.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for Android though! :)